# How to paginate, and filter at the same time?

Tags: database, sorting, filter, pagination

It seemed obvious, and the articles about the topic talk about either one or the other, but not both. I'm building a search dropdown (or autocomplete) with infinite scroll, and looking for a way to efficiently fetch the minimal possible data. Currently I'm using offset based pagination, and it worked well until I closely watched my search results. I'm using apollo-client 3 which caches my results.

For simplicity, I will have a simple database (just ids): `[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]`. Just for this example, the dropdown will only show one item at a time. My query is get 2 records, and skip current records.length (it will be the offset). The search box is empty, so I query for all records, get the first 2 (`a1`, and `a2`).

Then, I type in `b`, and get `b1`, and `b2`.
I scroll down to `b2`, and that is the last element on my list, so I fetch further 2, skipping the current length of my list, which is 2. There's only one item matching for `b`, if we skip 2, and it's `b3`.

Then I set the search box value to `3`. I already have `b3` in the cache, so it's loaded as the first element, but because it's the last as well, I fetch 2 more, skipping one matching the search results. In the database the first element matching `3` is `a3`, which will be skipped. Instead, `b3` will be returned as duplicate, and `c3`.

This is my problem, and I can only think of 2 ways to solve it:

- remove caching, and always load all records backwards as well (so on the 10th "page", load the previous 9 as well always), which doesn't seem too efficient
- instead of providing an offset, provide the list of items I already have, and skip them (where id is not in existing), which doesn't seem too efficient either, as it's growing both for the api call, and for the database (for each item in the database, and for each id in the list, check if the record's id is not in the list of ids)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What database technology do you use?

Comment: MongoDB with mongoose